# snapcraft cannot pull from source

Tags: linux, package, debian, snapcraft, snap

I am trying to build a snap package. Whenever I run `snapcraft` I keep getting this error:

```
Failed to pull source: './local/my-app.zip'.
Please ensure the source path is correct and that it is accessible.
See "snapcraft help sources" for more information.
```

This is the source from my snapcraft.yaml:

```
parts:
  my-part:
    # See 'snapcraft plugins'
    source: "./local/my-app.zip"
    plugin: dump
```

And this is the result of `ls local` in the "snap" folder:

```
salihu@penguin:~/my-app/dist/my-apps/my-app-snap/snap$ ls local
my-app.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the "./" part of the path. It seems to throw things off. Should work with this:

```
parts:
  my-part:
    # See 'snapcraft plugins'
    source: local/my-app.zip
    plugin: dump
```